How an appointment (which includes start_datetime and end_datetime) can be stored in a database?
In a project of mine, I want to create a calendar where a teacher can create appointments for his/her free time and then students can book an appointment with the teacher to teach him/her. This is how it works:

The teacher selects a day let's say January 13, 2024.

Then for that day the teacher will select his free times that he can be appointed. For example
(18:00 - 18:30), (19:30 - 20:15), (20:30 - 21:00).


As you can see above the teacher on January 13, 2024, has three different free periods that he can be appointed.

The student will select January 13, 2024, and then he/she will select one of the three given periods by the teacher to book one of the times from the teacher.

What is my issue?
I am creating a table for teacher available times to store the free periods of the teacher. But how can I connect an end_time of an appointment to its start_time because in the table there will be many end and start times.
Here is the teacher's available times table:

Here is what I am trying to store:


Do you need to be able to split the available time into smaller appointments?

What is the specific problem you're having? Stating your ultimate goal is not a question. This isn't a discussion forum, we can't help you with the general design. Show some specific code and we'll help you fix it.

What do you mean by "how can I connect an end_time of an appointment to its start_time"? Just put start_time and end_time in the appointments table.

I want to select different periods of a day to be selected. I just don't know how to make a start_time of a free time connected to its end_time, since there will be many start and end times in the table. Take a look at the provided image of the table for more clarity.

Putting them in the same row of the table is what connects them. What's the problem?

The appointments table contains columns: teacher_id FK, student_id FK, start_date_time, end_date_time. So the start and end times are connected there.

Hmm, now I got it. But one more thing? why do we need the student_id? Is it to know that if the student has booked the appointment or not?

So the teacher will know who to expect at that time, and only that student can cancel the appointment.

You might want additional information like the reason for the appointment.
